# React get value of object from localstorge

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get data from localstorage.
I used useEffect. But when I want to get a value in object, I got problem.

```
const [carinfo, setCarInfo] = useState(); 

useEffect(() => { 
  const storedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("carData"));
  setCarInfo(storedData); 
  console.log(storedData.brand); 
}, []);

console.log(carinfo.brand);
```

> console.log(storedData.brand) is working.

> No console.log(carinfo.brand) is not working

I have this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'brand')

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you get the error because the effect hasn't happened yet. The first time your component renders, carinfo is undefined.

You can set an initial value to state to get around this:

```
const [carinfo, setCarInfo] = useState({});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `console.log(carinfo.brand)` is getting executed before the `useEffect`.
That means you're trying to access the value of `carinfo` before setting it.
Sol 1: Put the `console.log(carinfo.brand)` inside `useEffect`

Sol 2: If you need the `carinfo` outside `useEffect`, write it inside a function and call that function after setting the `carinfo` value

Answer (score 0):

On your initial render, the value of `carinfo` will match what you call `useState` with.

`useState()` is the equivalent of `useState(undefined)`. `undefined` is a value without a `brand` property.

`useEffect` will fire and then update the state with whatever value you have in `localStorage`, given that it matches your expected data structure (you may want to consider creating a safer way get to `localStorage`.

Nevertheless,only after the initial render is the state set, and then you may have the expected value in `carinfo`.

You can use optional chaining to protect yourself, `console.log(carinfo?.brand)` or some other way to handle the undefined case.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers cover the reasons of the Exception, this is just the simplest fix:

```
console.log(carinfo?.brand);
```